# XML -> Progress 10 DB temp-table

Tags: xml, progress-4gl

Here is what I am trying, didn't even get to the point of looking at the temp table yet, can't even create it properly:

4GL Code:

```
DEFINE VARIABLE cSourceType             AS CHARACTER NO-UNDO.
DEFINE VARIABLE cReadMode               AS CHARACTER NO-UNDO.
DEFINE VARIABLE lOverrideDefaultMapping AS LOGICAL   NO-UNDO.
DEFINE VARIABLE cFile                   AS CHARACTER NO-UNDO.
DEFINE VARIABLE cSchemaLocation         AS CHARACTER NO-UNDO.
DEFINE VARIABLE cFieldTypeMapping       AS CHARACTER NO-UNDO.
DEFINE VARIABLE cVerifySchemaMode       AS CHARACTER NO-UNDO.
DEFINE VARIABLE lRetOK                  AS LOGICAL   NO-UNDO.
DEFINE VARIABLE ttOrd                   AS HANDLE    NO-UNDO.

CREATE TEMP-TABLE ttOrd.
ASSIGN
  cSourceType             = "file"
  cFile                   = "ORD1.xml" 
  cReadMode               = "empty"
  cSchemaLocation         = "Orders.xsd"
  lOverrideDefaultMapping = ?
  cFieldTypeMapping       = ?
  cVerifySchemaMode       = ?.

lRetOK = ttOrd:READ-XML(cSourceType, cFile, cReadMode, cSchemaLocation,
  lOverrideDefaultMapping, cFieldTypeMapping, cVerifySchemaMode).
```

ERROR I GET:

> Invalid inner element name 'ORDER' for Temp-Table definition. (14748)
> Unable to create Temp-Table or dataset schema from XML Schema. (13032)
> Procedure complete. Press space bar to continue.

Orders.xsd file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
   <xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" elementFormDefault="qualified" attributeFormDefault="unqualified">
         <!-- XML Schema Generated from XML Document on Mon Mar 08 2021 10:09:16 GMT-0500 (Eastern Standard Time) -->
         <!-- with XmlGrid.net Free Online Service http://xmlgrid.net -->
         <xs:element name="EXPORTEDORDERS">
               <xs:complexType>
                     <xs:sequence>
                           <xs:element name="ORDERS">
                                 <xs:complexType>
                                       <xs:sequence>
                                             <xs:element name="ORDER" maxOccurs="unbounded">
                                                   <xs:complexType>
                                                         <xs:sequence>
                                                               <xs:element name="CUSTNO" type="xs:string"></xs:element>
                                                               <xs:element name="ORDERNO" type="xs:int"></xs:element>
                                                               <xs:element name="RELEASE_DT" type="xs:string"></xs:element>
                                                               <xs:element name="FULLNAME" type="xs:string"></xs:element>
                                                               <xs:element name="PONUM" type="xs:int"></xs:element>
                                                               <xs:element name="DESCR"></xs:element>
                                                               <xs:element name="TOT_AMT" type="xs:double"></xs:element>
                                                               <xs:element name="BO_AMT" type="xs:int"></xs:element>
                                                               <xs:element name="COMMITAMT" type="xs:int"></xs:element>
                                                               <xs:element name="TERMS" type="xs:string"></xs:element>
                                                               <xs:element name="STATUS" type="xs:string"></xs:element>
                                                               <xs:element name="SALESREP" type="xs:string"></xs:element>
                                                               <xs:element name="SALESEMAIL"></xs:element>
                                                               <xs:element name="INVNO"></xs:element>
                                                               <xs:element name="GROSS" type="xs:int"></xs:element>
                                                               <xs:element name="FREIGHT" type="xs:int"></xs:element>
                                                               <xs:element name="INS" type="xs:int"></xs:element>
                                                               <xs:element name="TAX" type="xs:int"></xs:element>
                                                               <xs:element name="COD_CHG" type="xs:int"></xs:element>
                                                               <xs:element name="ORDER_DT" type="xs:string"></xs:element>
                                                               <xs:element name="CLOSED_DT"></xs:element>
                                                               <xs:element name="POST_DT"></xs:element>
                                                               <xs:element name="INV_DT"></xs:element>
                                                               <xs:element name="SHIP_DT" type="xs:string"></xs:element>
                                                               <xs:element name="SHIP_METH" type="xs:string"></xs:element>
                                                               <xs:element name="WH_NUM"></xs:element>
                                                               <xs:element name="DIV_NUM" type="xs:int"></xs:element>
                                                               <xs:element name="SH_REL_DT"></xs:element>
                                                               <xs:element name="REL_WH_DT"></xs:element>
                                                               <xs:element name="CURR_CODE" type="xs:string"></xs:element>
                                                               <xs:element name="EXCH_RATE" type="xs:int"></xs:element>
                                                               <xs:element name="LAST_MOD_DT" type="xs:string"></xs:element>
                                                               <xs:element name="FLEX_FLD1" type="xs:int"></xs:element>
                                                               <xs:element name="FLEX_FLD2" type="xs:int"></xs:element>
                                                               <xs:element name="FLEX_FLD3" type="xs:int"></xs:element>
                                                               <xs:element name="FLEX_FLD4" type="xs:string"></xs:element>
                                                               <xs:element name="FLEX_FLD5"></xs:element>
                                                               <xs:element name="FLEX_FLD6"></xs:element>
                                                               <xs:element name="FLEX_FLD7"></xs:element>
                                                               <xs:element name="FLEX_FLD8"></xs:element>
                                                               <xs:element name="FLEX_FLD9"></xs:element>
                                                               <xs:element name="PENDING_NOTES"></xs:element>
                                                               <xs:element name="RELEASE_NOTES"></xs:element>
                                                         </xs:sequence>
                                                   </xs:complexType>
                                             </xs:element>
                                       </xs:sequence>
                                 </xs:complexType>
                           </xs:element>
                     </xs:sequence>
               </xs:complexType>
         </xs:element>
   </xs:schema>
```

ORD1.xml File:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<EXPORTEDORDERS>
    <ORDERS>
        <ORDER>
            <CUSTNO>V70-50200022BL01</CUSTNO>
            <ORDERNO>297740</ORDERNO>
            <RELEASE_DT>09-24-2020</RELEASE_DT>
            <FULLNAME>GETPAID Administrator</FULLNAME>
            <PONUM>9010066064</PONUM>
            <DESCR></DESCR>
            <TOT_AMT>7066.50</TOT_AMT>
            <BO_AMT>0.00</BO_AMT>
            <COMMITAMT>0.00</COMMITAMT>
            <TERMS>NET 60</TERMS>
            <STATUS>APR-REL</STATUS>
            <SALESREP>NONE</SALESREP>
            <SALESEMAIL></SALESEMAIL>
            <INVNO></INVNO>
            <GROSS>3660.00</GROSS>
            <FREIGHT>0.00</FREIGHT>
            <INS>0.00</INS>
            <TAX>0.00</TAX>
            <COD_CHG>0.00</COD_CHG>
            <ORDER_DT>03-02-2020</ORDER_DT>
            <CLOSED_DT></CLOSED_DT>
            <POST_DT></POST_DT>
            <INV_DT></INV_DT>
            <SHIP_DT>04-21-2020</SHIP_DT>
            <SHIP_METH>WSI</SHIP_METH>
            <WH_NUM></WH_NUM>
            <DIV_NUM>0</DIV_NUM>
            <SH_REL_DT></SH_REL_DT>
            <REL_WH_DT></REL_WH_DT>
            <CURR_CODE>USD</CURR_CODE>
            <EXCH_RATE>0.00</EXCH_RATE>
            <LAST_MOD_DT>03-02-2020</LAST_MOD_DT>
            <FLEX_FLD1>0.00</FLEX_FLD1>
            <FLEX_FLD2>0.00</FLEX_FLD2>
            <FLEX_FLD3>0.00</FLEX_FLD3>
            <FLEX_FLD4>GLOVIA</FLEX_FLD4>
            <FLEX_FLD5></FLEX_FLD5>
            <FLEX_FLD6></FLEX_FLD6>
            <FLEX_FLD7></FLEX_FLD7>
            <FLEX_FLD8></FLEX_FLD8>
            <FLEX_FLD9></FLEX_FLD9>
            <PENDING_NOTES></PENDING_NOTES>
            <RELEASE_NOTES></RELEASE_NOTES>
        </ORDER>
    </ORDERS>
</EXPORTEDORDERS>
```

Comment: The code you are showing makes no attempt to define a temp-table. Which makes the error that you have shared very puzzling. Have you posted the correct code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In 10.1c this actually works now:

```
DEFINE VARIABLE cSourceType             AS CHARACTER NO-UNDO.
DEFINE VARIABLE cReadMode               AS CHARACTER NO-UNDO.
DEFINE VARIABLE lOverrideDefaultMapping AS LOGICAL   NO-UNDO.
DEFINE VARIABLE cFile                   AS CHARACTER NO-UNDO.
DEFINE VARIABLE cSchemaLocation         AS CHARACTER NO-UNDO.
DEFINE VARIABLE cFieldTypeMapping       AS CHARACTER NO-UNDO.
DEFINE VARIABLE cVerifySchemaMode       AS CHARACTER NO-UNDO.
DEFINE VARIABLE lRetOK                  AS LOGICAL   NO-UNDO.

DEFINE TEMP-TABLE ORDERS NO-UNDO 
   FIELD parentid AS RECID 
. 

DEFINE TEMP-TABLE ORDER
  FIELD parentid AS RECID 
  FIELD custno   AS CHARACTER 
  FIELD ORDERNO as CHARACTER 
  FIELD RELEASE_DT as CHARACTER 
  FIELD FULLNAME as CHARACTER 
  FIELD PONUM as CHARACTER 
  FIELD DESCR as CHARACTER 
  FIELD TOT_AMT as decimal 
  FIELD BO_AMT as decimal 
  FIELD COMMITAMT as decimal 
  FIELD TERMS as CHARACTER 
  FIELD STATUS1 as CHARACTER 
  FIELD SALESREP as CHARACTER 
  FIELD SALESEMAIL as CHARACTER 
  FIELD INVNO as CHARACTER 
  FIELD GROSS as decimal 
  FIELD FREIGHT as decimal 
  FIELD INS as decimal 
  FIELD TAX as decimal 
  FIELD COD_CHG as decimal 
  FIELD ORDER_DT as CHARACTER 
  FIELD CLOSED_DT as CHARACTER 
  FIELD POST_DT as CHARACTER 
  FIELD INV_DT as CHARACTER 
  FIELD SHIP_DT as CHARACTER 
  FIELD SHIP_METH as CHARACTER 
  FIELD WH_NUM as CHARACTER 
  FIELD DIV_NUM as int 
  FIELD SH_REL_DT as CHARACTER 
  FIELD REL_WH_DT as CHARACTER 
  FIELD CURR_CODE as CHARACTER 
  FIELD EXCH_RATE as decimal 
  FIELD LAST_MOD_DT as CHARACTER 
  FIELD FLEX_FLD1 as CHARACTER 
  FIELD FLEX_FLD2 as CHARACTER 
  FIELD FLEX_FLD3 as CHARACTER 
  FIELD FLEX_FLD4 as CHARACTER 
  FIELD FLEX_FLD5 as CHARACTER 
  FIELD FLEX_FLD6 as CHARACTER 
  FIELD FLEX_FLD7 as CHARACTER 
  FIELD FLEX_FLD8 as CHARACTER 
  FIELD FLEX_FLD9 as CHARACTER 
  FIELD PENDING_NOTES as CHARACTER 
  FIELD RELEASE_NOTES as CHARACTER 
.  

DEFINE DATASET dsExportedOrders FOR ORDERS, ORDER
   DATA-RELATION drOrderLine FOR ORDERS, ORDER RELATION-FIELDS (parentid, parentid)
.

ASSIGN
   cSourceType             = "file"
   cFile                   = "ORD2.xml" 
   cReadMode               = "empty"
   lOverrideDefaultMapping = ?
   cFieldTypeMapping       = ?
   cVerifySchemaMode       = ?
.

lRetOK = DATASET dsExportedOrders:READ-XML(cSourceType, cFile, cReadMode, cSchemaLocation,
  lOverrideDefaultMapping, cFieldTypeMapping, cVerifySchemaMode).
    
FOR EACH ORDER:
   Display 
      custno
      orderno
      status1
   .   
END.
```

Comment: @Jensd with the above working I have one last issue. My XML has a field <STATUS> and that is a keyword and I cannot have a temp-table field names STATUS (it looks like) and I have determined that in 10.1c (version I have to run in right now, "SERIALIZED-NAME" does not work. So in the above code, how would I get XML field <STATUS> into the temp-table. I don't care what I call in in the temp-table. I just need to get it there.

Answer (score 0):

10.2... Ouch!

Use a dataset instead. I think they were available. Also, I'm skipping the schema. It's really not any help and lastly I statically define the dataset and temp-table because it will make your life easier.

```
DEFINE VARIABLE cSourceType             AS CHARACTER NO-UNDO.
DEFINE VARIABLE cReadMode               AS CHARACTER NO-UNDO.
DEFINE VARIABLE lOverrideDefaultMapping AS LOGICAL   NO-UNDO.
DEFINE VARIABLE cFile                   AS CHARACTER NO-UNDO.
DEFINE VARIABLE cSchemaLocation         AS CHARACTER NO-UNDO.
DEFINE VARIABLE cFieldTypeMapping       AS CHARACTER NO-UNDO.
DEFINE VARIABLE cVerifySchemaMode       AS CHARACTER NO-UNDO.
DEFINE VARIABLE lRetOK                  AS LOGICAL   NO-UNDO.

DEFINE TEMP-TABLE ttOrders NO-UNDO SERIALIZE-NAME "ORDERS"
    FIELD parentid AS RECID SERIALIZE-HIDDEN. //Disregard this field

DEFINE TEMP-TABLE ttOrd NO-UNDO SERIALIZE-NAME "ORDER"
    FIELD parentid AS RECID SERIALIZE-HIDDEN
    FIELD custno   AS CHARACTER SERIALIZE-NAME "CUSTNO"
    /* Rest of fields here.... */.

DEFINE DATASET dsExportOrders SERIALIZE-NAME "EXPORTEDORDERS"
    FOR ttOrders, ttOrd
    PARENT-ID-RELATION FOR ttOrders, ttOrd PARENT-ID-FIELD parentId.
    
 
ASSIGN
  cSourceType             = "file"
  cFile                   = "c:\temp\ORD1.xml" 
  cReadMode               = "empty"
  //cSchemaLocation         = "c:\temp\Orders.xsd"
  lOverrideDefaultMapping = ?
  cFieldTypeMapping       = ?
  cVerifySchemaMode       = ?.


lRetOK = DATASET dsExportOrders:READ-XML(cSourceType, cFile, cReadMode, cSchemaLocation,
  lOverrideDefaultMapping, cFieldTypeMapping, cVerifySchemaMode).
  
FOR EACH ttOrd:
    DISPLAY ttOrd.
END.
```

Comment: You haven't changed names on the temp-table or the dataset?

Comment: Comments isnt the best place for code etc. Have you changed the name of the temp-table ttOrd?